# Bidirection support for ckeditor5

Tags: ckeditor5, bidi

Is there a way to add bidirection support for ckeditor5. I need to be able to change direction for block-level content element. In ckeditor4 there was a [BiDi plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/bidi), But I couldn't find anything for ckeditor5. Is there any existing solution available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support yet.

You can use this 3rd party plugin for basic support.

https://github.com/abedi-ir/ckeditor5-direction